# Maven upgrade breaks mule maven-release plugin

Tags: maven, mule, maven-release-plugin

After upgrading to Maven 3.3.9, when doing a mvn release:perform Maven builds and uploads a -SNAPSHOT instead of the release version.

Simple reverting the Maven version fixes the issue and the 100% same command works fine.

I have to admit that it could be because we use the Mule Maven plugin. But looks more like Maven bug then a Mule issue.

Plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <appDirectory>${basedir}/target/mule-resources</appDirectory>
                                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
        <inclusions>
            <inclusion>                                                         <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            </inclusion>
            <inclusion>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.utils</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-dbserver-module</artifactId>
            </inclusion>
        </inclusions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>                                              
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Edit:** Mule tools version:

```
<mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
```

This seems to me like a Maven bug. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the error message ? Which version of release plugin do you use? The maven-assembly-plugin should be updated as well...What version of mule-app-maven-plugin?

Comment: Done, see attached: mule.tools.version

Comment: Can you paste your `release.properties` file before executing `release:perform` and the relevant log parts when executing both `release:prepare` and `release:perform`?

Comment: Apparently it's neither a Maven nor Java version is but a Git issue. In some Git version they changed some responses in the git comments that Maven uses to determine the package names. Still investigating how to resolve it though.